Как в библиотеке Tkinter сохранить число, которое ввёл пользователь?
Не мог бы кто-нибудь подсказать, как я могу использовать значение, вводимое пользователем (переменную entry_text в коде) в дальнейшем?
Я пробовала использовать глобальные переменные и классы, но проблема в том, что функция print_entry_text() не запускается, пока не будет нажата клавиша Enter, и остальная часть кода выполнятся раньше, поэтому при выполнении данного кода возникает ошибка.
Прошу прощения, если мне не удалось сформулировать свою проблему внятно, это мой первый вопрос на этом сайте.
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Математические игры")
root.geometry("500x500")

def print_entry_text(event):
    global entry_text
    entry_text = entry.get()

entry = Entry(root, width=4)
entry.pack()
entry.bind("<Return>", print_entry_text)
print(entry_text)

root.mainloop()


Запишите на верхнем уровне в entry_text какое-то значение по умолчанию. Можно None, чтобы можно было отличить от значения, введенного пользователем. Там где планируете использовать - добавьте проверку на None. Ну и нет особого смысла сразу при старте программы пытаться вывести, что ввел пользователь, он гарантированно не успеет это сделать.

Проблема с формулировкой. "В библиотеке Tkinter сохранить число" - мягко говоря, не из той оперы. Определить переменную и использовать её значение - примерно так. У Вас entry_text = entry.get() находится внутри функции print_entry_text и естественно, не может быть выполнено просто так, без вызова функции. В данном случае по нажатию "".  Строка entry_text = entry.get() может быть выполнена вне функции в любом месте в случае, когда определение поля entry = Entry(root, width=4) уже выполнено. Кстати, переменная entry_text определена категорически неправильно, её статус надо отслеживать.

Не уверен что правильно понял вас, но попробуйте так:
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Математические игры")
root.geometry("500x500")

entry_text = ''                                          # +++   

def print_entry_text(event):
#    global entry_text
    entry_text = entry.get()
    print(f'entry_text={entry_text};')                   # +++

entry = Entry(root, width=4)
entry.pack()
entry.bind("<Return>", print_entry_text)       
print(entry_text, '\n-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\n')

root.mainloop()

